# TeXLive 2019 tlshell bug

Tags: bugs

I installed TexLive 2019 under WIN10 but tlmgr-GUI doesn´t run.

Siep answered: 
*"This is known and is a packaging error. It should be fixed in a few days. The command-line tlmgr should be unaffected."*

My questions are:

1. When the bug will be fixed - how can I modify my Texlife (tlmgr doesn´t work)?
2. What can I do in the meantime? My TexLife 2018 worked very well but as I´m a total beginner in writing command lines I would need a how-to-do step-by-step answer.

Thanks

Comment: Simply type in a command line e.g. `tlmgr update --list` and hit enter to get a list of open updates and `tlmgr update --all` to install them.

Comment: 1. This is not the place to report bugs and in my opinion it is kind of rude asking for ETA.  People working on TeX Live are doing so in their free time.  2. Read the documentation: http://tug.org/texlive/doc.html

Comment: try to add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;%PATH% at the begining or tlmr.bat. It fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @gigiair IMO if that is needed then your Windows does not have a correct PATH setting. In version prior to Win10 it was easy to accidentally delte the PATH setting thereby destroying any use of the command line. This should not be the case in Win10.

Comment: @HenriMenke maybe it's a language problem, but I don't think the OP asks for an ETA on the bugfix. Instead he means something like "the bug is that updating does not work, so at the time that the bugfix is released, how will I be able to install the update with the fix?"

Comment: @daleif : I am not a ms-windows user nor hacker. cmd.exe works fine when called from Super key+R but not from within tlmgr.bat. I just installed TL19 for for curiosity on ms-windows

Comment: test: can you run cmd.exe from within cmd.exe? And exactly with windows version are you using this on.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help. After three nights of try & error tlmgr.shell (GPU) is working. Main problem was to run cmd.exe as an administrator which was a bit complicated on my PC. I had to start cmd.exe direct from the WIN32-directory (links doesn´t work) In the next step I used the commands which Ulrike suggested. I got the message that an update of tlmgr itself was necessary. After this update I could update tex-files as Ulrike showed in her comment (thanks it was exactly I needed). At last I would like to apologise for my wording. I respect everybody who ist programming LaTex.